# Google Analytics: track from inbound link to sale

Tags: google-analytics

I need to be able to track whether particular inbound links from an external site result in individual sales - is that possible with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Traffic Sources -> Sources-> Referals. Klick on the domain name to drill down to the url level. On the top of the page hit the "Ecommerce" Tab. This will give you the number of sales for that link, but not indivdual transactions.

If you need to get down to indivdual transactions your best bet is to ask the external site to add campaign parameters to the link (see here : http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867), build a custom segement based on the campaign name and apply this to the conversions->transactions display.

On second thought, you might be able to build a segment based on the referal path (so no need for campaign parameters), but I haven't tested this. Worth a try, though.